# Vue Component not rendering when clicking v-btn with route assigned

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuetify.js

I am having trouble getting a component to load.

I have a Navbar with a Drawer with routes to each main page of my web app.

So far I have been able to make a page titled "Weapons.vue" which shows a list of weapon Categories in a video game ( such as Sniper Rifles and Handguns ). I use the "data()" to pass in names, images, and routes. Clicking on one of these weapons category v-btn brings me to a page which displays weapons within a category. In this question, I will be talking about "Assault-rifles.vue".

The issue I am having is that I am able to get to the `Assault-Rifles.vue` page whenever I click the v-tn with the assigned routes, but when I try to do the same thing within the `Assault-rifles.vue` page , by using v-btn and specified routes to get to a specific weapon , will bring me to an empty component. The path I specified shows in the URL, but it isn't displaying my "ADAR.vue" component ( ADAR is a type of weapon in the game ).

Here is my App.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <Navbar />
    <v-content class="mt-5--grey mx-5--grey black">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { Navbar },
  data: () => ({
    //
  })
};
</script>
```

Here is my Weapons.vue (where the user should start). Didn't add all the data in the data() to save space.

```html
<template>
  <div class="mx-5 mb-5">
    <h1 class="green--text ma-5">Weapons</h1>
    <v-container class="my-5">
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 s6 m4 lg3 v-for="weapon in WeaponCat" :key="weapon.weapontype">
          <v-card class="text-md-center ma-3 grey darken-4">
            <v-responsive class="pt-4">
              <v-img contain :src="weapon.images"></v-img>
            </v-responsive>
            <v-card-title class="justify-center">
              <div class="heading font-weight-black white--text">{{ weapon.WeaponType}}</div>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-actions class="justify-center">
              <v-btn flat class="green black--text ma-3" :to="weapon.route">View Weapons</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      WeaponCat: [
        {
          WeaponType: "Assault Rifles",
          images: "/WeaponCatimages/AR.png",
          route: "/weapons/Assault-Rifles"
        },
        .....
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is my Assault Rifles Category pages ( Assault-Rifles.vue ). Again removed some data to save space.

```html
<template>
  <div class="mx-4 Armor">
    <h1 class="green--text ma-5">Assault Rifles</h1>
    <v-container class="my-5">
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 s6 m4 lg3 v-for="weapon in Weapon" :key="weapon.weapon">
          <v-card class="text-md-center ma-3 grey darken-4">
            <v-responsive class="pt-4">
              <v-img contain :src="weapon.images"></v-img>
            </v-responsive>
            <v-card-title class="justify-center">
              <div class="heading font-weight-black white--text">{{ weapon.Weapon}}</div>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-actions class="justify-center">
              <v-btn flat class="green black--text ma-3" :to="weapon.route">View Stats</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Weapon: [
        {
          Weapon: "ADAR",
          images: "/WeaponIMG/AR/ADAR_2-15.png",
          route: "/weapons/Assault-Rifles/ADAR"
        },
        ....
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is my "ADAR.vue" component ( the one that wont render ).

```html
<template>
  <div class="mx-4 ADAR">
    <h1 class="white--text">ADAR</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

Here is my route.js . It is super long so i removed some things...

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Home from "./views/Home.vue";
import Weapons from "./views/Weapons.vue";
import AssaultRifles from "./views/AssaultRifles.vue";
import ADAR from "./views/ADAR.vue";


Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/armor",
      name: "armor",
      component: Armor
    },

    {
      path: "/weapons",
      name: "weapons",
      component: Weapons
    },

    {
      path: "/weapons/Assault-Rifles",
      name: "Assault Rifles",
      component: AssaultRifles
    },

    {
      path: "/Weapons/Assault-Rilfes/ADAR",
      name: "ADAR",
      component: ADAR
    },
  ]
});
```

I have tried and tried multiple things such as changing if "/" appears and capitalization and I just cant seem to find the answer anywhere. I would love some help on this please.

Comment: when you go to that route directly by entering URL in browser, does this route work this way?

Comment: No it does not. Also, I have an image in my nav bar and it goes away sometimes when I reload the page.

I tried going directly to http://localhost:8080/weapons/Assault-Rifles/ADAR and it did not work.

Comment: I might also add that my "weapons" page is showing http://localhost:8080/Weapons ( with a capital W) and I am not sure if this matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route path says `/Weapons/Assault-Rilfes/ADAR`, note the misspell `Rilfes`.

Also you might want to use lowercase for the whole URL, it looks neater imo.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much Flame, you're the best!

Sorry for not being able to find such a simple mistake.